# Best way to store a value which could be multiple types

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'd like to re-ask [a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109293/proper-way-to-store-a-value-that-could-be-multiple-different-types) in a more direct and general way:

How do you create a table to store values which could be multiple different types?

In my case, the values provide diagnostics about an event. Ex: Event occurred -> Store readings from multiple PLC's which contain pertinent information about the event. The PLC's could monitor any type of data.

Some examples I can think of:

- Create a column for every possible type and create another column to indicate which column to use

  - Ex: Cols: IntVal, StrVal, BoolVal, Type. Vals: null, null, True, "BOOL"
- Store the values no matter what as a varchar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would appear that you have already been told that you are straying down the road to the [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Take a look at the [image here](http://karwin.blogspot.ie/2009/05/eav-fail.html) for why the EAV model should be avoided at virtually all costs.

Bill Karwin, the author responsible for the image above, has written a book ["SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356557) and he devotes the first chapter to the EAV anti-pattern. He's also a big hitter on this group and **huge** on StackOverflow (for database issues).

My advice would be to have a table for each type of result and then to use `VIEW`s to combine them when necessary.

As an example, you could have

```
CREATE TABLE char_result
(
  question_id INT,
  user_id INT,
  cresult CHAR,
  result_correct BOOLEAN (or equivalent in your RDBMS)
  ..
  <other stuff>
  ..
);
```

Do the same for num_result, except substitute nresult INT (FLOAT... whatever) for cresult - same idea for VARCHAR &c.

Then create `VIEW`s over your different result tables for `result_correct` (and other fields - `number_of_attempts`... &c. - whatever your other fields are). In this case, you are comparing like with like and not peforming calculations equivalent to adding population to altitude as per the hilarious image referenced above!

Comment: As a counter to Bill, I've written in favor of EAV here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway

Comment: I don't think having multiple possible types for the same logical column constitutes an EAV. I think he's looking for a "variant/object" type. That's much easier to do with a few columns than one table per type. That sounds very inconvenient. And after the view is created it's really the same thing as creating the types in the same table in the first place.

Comment: @usr I'd be interested in seeing your solution.

Comment: Just one column per type seems alright to me. I have done it like that in the past. It's the least bad solution. Here's another argument: What if there were *two* variably typed columns. This answer's solution requires a quadratic number of tables. One could split it into a basic table plus N*M more tables... This does not seem right.

Comment: @usr isn't one problem with your solution that none of those columns can be `NOT NULL`? Personally, I'm a big believer in having a `NOT NULL` constaint [whenever possible](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140410/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-specifying-not-null-in-postgresql-for-fields-wh/140416#140416).

Comment: Yes, that's a downside. Mitigate using a check constraint. Still not good for tooling (ORMs and IDE autocompletion) but it's not too bad I think. It's still runtime NOT NULL, just not statically discoverable. The first test run will find most such bugs. I fully agree with the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

I think if it was absolutely necessary to store a value this way in a relational database, I'd use a solution like [Microsoft SQL Server's JSON columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).